# mod_rewrite with Joomla and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a kind of Joomla and WordPress mashup.

The Joomla site is in the web Root directory (httpdocs directory) and the WordPress site is in a sub directory (jobs subdirectory).

I have a PHP script that uses a long query string placed in the WordPress directory:

```
http://example.com/jobs/search.php?search=true&auth=AUTHCODE&skills=developer&andor=OR&timescale=6&areas=&andor_areas=OR&posted=1
```

I would like this to be rewritten to something like:

```
http://example.com/jobs/search/true/AUTHCODE/developer/OR/6//OR/1
```

I have tried many mod_rewite rules using  the mod_rewrite generators online and they do not work. I get "page not found" from the standard WordPress warning.

I have tested mod_rewite rules both in the Joomla .htaccess file and the WordPress .htaccess file.

I have tried various different combinations of the  code below using:

```
RewriteRule ^/jobs/cvsearch/
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^cvsearch/
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/cvsearch/
```

at the beginning of the rule with no luck.

An example of what I have tried is below, in the WordPress .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jobs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /jobs/index.php [L]
RewriteRule /jobs/search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /jobs/search.php?search=$1&auth=$2&skills=$3&andor=$4&timescale=$5&areas=$6&andor_areas=$7&posted=$8 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Joomla .htaccess file is below (shown as it comes with Joomla package):

```
##
 # @version $Id: htaccess.txt 10492 2008-07-02 06:38:28Z ircmaxell $
 # @package Joomla
 # @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2008 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
 # @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
 # Joomla! is Free Software
 ##


 #####################################################
 #  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
 #
 # The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
 # with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
 # be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
 # your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
 # beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
 # it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
 #
 #####################################################

 ##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
 Options +FollowSymLinks

 #
 #  mod_rewrite in use

 RewriteEngine On

 ########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
 ## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
 ## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
 #
 # Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
 # Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
 # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
 # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
 # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
 # Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
 #
 ########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

 #  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
 #  is not directly related to physical file paths.
 #  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

 # RewriteBase /


 ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
 #
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) index.php
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
 #
 ########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

The directory part of the URLs in the RewriteRule is the confusing part for me as I am not sure on how it should be constructed.

Also, could the Joomla or WordPress .htaccess rules be affecting the mod_rewrite that I am trying to attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You placed your mod_rewite rule too low, it should be right after your `RewriteBase /jobs/`.

The caret symbol was missing from the mod_rewrite rule and has been added into my supplied Apache mod_rewrite .htaccess code. What you had was this: `RewriteRule /jobs/search/ etc.` but should have been this: `RewriteRule ^/search/ etc.`

Since you already declared the RewriteBase as */jobs/*, `RewriteRule /jobs/search/ etc.` is not necessary and has to be changed to simply using `RewriteRule ^/search/ etc.` minus the */jobs/* part.

Additionally, I added in a temporary 307 re-direct, non case sensitive rule to the mod_rewrite rule.

**The Apache mod_rewrite .htaccess Code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jobs/
RewriteRule ^/search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /jobs/search.php?search=$1&auth=$2&skills=$3&andor=$4&timescale=$5&areas=$6&andor_areas=$7&posted=$8 [R=307,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /jobs/index.php [L]
```